# Why is the derivative of activation function all positive?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, activation-functions

All the activation functions I see have positive derivatives.
Will negative ReLU work as well as its positive counterpart or will it lead to instability?

Answer (score 1):

By definition from wikipedia:

> Let $\varphi$ be a nonconstant, bounded, and continuous function.

This is also being proven for ReLU and other functions that violets some of those properties... however, if you take `1 - sigmoid(x)` as your activation, all the properties are satisfied, and the derivative is strictly negative

This can be more "popularly" be seen also in the max-out activation function